# Want to make panel longer than form in visual studio

Tags: c#

I have a long form I have to translate into c# from access, and the length of the form is longer than the maximum height VS will allow in the design window. How can I make a panel that is large enough inside the form, if at all? I have tried turning on autoscroll, manually adjusting panel height, and click-dragging resize boxes for both the form and the panel. Any pointers?

Comment: winforms? asp.net webforms?

Comment: What happens when you enter the height you want for your Panel into its __property panel__? Note that form sizes are limited. But with form.autoscroll a larger panel with show along with scrollbars.

Comment: winforms, and nothing, entering values into the property panel was what i meant by "manually." should have been more specific

Answer (score 0):

Eventually figured it out, creating an object and then pressing the down key to move it out of the window shortens the scrollbar enough to move it and therefore move the page.